# We have a YouTube channel

Tags: discussion, site-promotion, blog, game-on

You can find it here: http://www.youtube.com/user/GamingSE

At the moment it's a bit sparse, but that will be changing soon. If you have any videos you would like to put on it, Speak to us in [the Bridge](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/35/the-bridge). And don't forget to subscribe!

**Upload rules:**

- It must be relevant to Gaming.StackExchange. Either for the blog or the main site.
- Original content only. No re-uploads of trailers or other people's game play. They must have a voice over at the very least.
- Any content that requires a detailed description to go with it (it doesn't make sense on its own) should be marked as unlisted.
- Upload as private, edit then make it public. This avoids people watching videos that are not finished.

Comment: A reminder to everyone: Even if you don't necessarily plan on watching everything here, please Subscribe and Like videos (or Dislike with a reason if you feel the need). Youtube treats subs, views, and Likes like SE treats rep. The more you have, the more privileges you get. The sooner the account gets more subs/views/likes, the sooner it can upload longer videos. Please help us get there!

Comment: @FallenAngelEyes Actually [all you need for that is validating a mobile number, plus having a _perfect_ course copyright-wise.](http://www.google.com/support/youtube/bin/answer.py?hl=en&answer=71673)

Comment: @badp Oh, well then, strike that!

Comment: But if we get popular enough we could get YouTube partnership and get money for prizes/servers/free games.